# Access particular server behind load-balanced tomcat

Tags: tomcat, load-balancing, mod-proxy

I'm building production configuration where 2 tomcats are sitting behind the apache with load-balancer and mod_proxy. What I need is the script which checks whether particular instance of tomcat is running. The problem is I use AJP connector in tomcat. Is it possible to issue HTTP request to apache somehow that I make sure only needed instance of tomcat will respond?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [mod_proxy_balancer](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html)
But most parts of balancer are documented in [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

If you revers proxy to a balancer, the balancer will choose a backend which is available.